# how to set up a wait for the process to run down

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm dealing with a situation where I need a cypress to wait for me to finish the snapshot creation process. But the process takes different lengths and I don't know how to handle it in terms of waiting. Can anyone advise me how to do this?

[image]
[image]

I need the test to finish after verifying that it has been successfully created. I can use cy.wait(500), but this is not optimal. Do you have anybody some tips?

When done, I see done, but the problem is that I only need to work with a certain line and let the older ones be. I don't know how to tell.

[image]

Comment: Please add the html for the percentage value when the image process is complete.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand now?

Comment: So I could see while the processing is happening, there is a percentage value, what happens when the processing is complete, does it turn to 100%?

Comment: yes exactly to 100%

Comment: Can you add the html of that, when there is 100% displayed?

Comment: oh yes, something like cy.get('.dx-item-content').contains('100%') ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. `should` assertion will wait and keep on retrying till cypress gets 100%.

```js
cy.get('selector', {timeout: 8000}).should('have.text', '100%')
```

You can play with the timeout values.

Comment: but the problem is that status is changed randomly. Once it displays 41%, the second time it doesn't and it displays 90% ...

Comment: That is why I wanted to see the html when the processing is complete how it looks like, so that I can come with up a more accurate solution.

Comment: When done, I see done (i updated my post), but the problem is that I only need to work with a certain line and let the older ones be. I don't know how to tell.